# Loading table rows on demand using react WayPoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, waypoint

I'm using a hybrid of material UI table and react-table. When the number of rows in the table exceeds ~200 rows the performance is not that good. So I'm trying to display a fixed number of rows (assume 20 rows) at the beginning and whenever I scroll down a callback should fire that appends rows to existing rows. I'm using react-waypoint to initiate a callback but unable to figure out how to append rows to the end of the current list. Here is my Table component.

```
export default function TmpTable(props) {
  let data = props.rows;
  let columns = props.columns;
  const {getTableProps,getTableBodyProps,headerGroups,rows,prepareRow,} = useTable({columns,data,});
  let slicedRows= [];
  //considering only few rows
  slicedRows = rows.slice(0, 10);

  return (
    <TableContainer style={{ maxHeight: "350px" }}>
      <Table size="small" stickyHeader>
        <TableHead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={column.id}
                  id={"columns" + column.Header}
                >
                  <span>{column.render("Header")}</span>
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {slicedRows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <>
              <TableRow {...row.getRowProps()} style={{ height: "35px" }}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <TableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                      {cell.render("Cell")}
                    </TableCell>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
              <Waypoint onEnter={() => console.log('need to add a callback that adds more rows')}/>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

I'm aware of react-window to virtualize rows but I've already created a complex table with expanding rows, checkboxes for row selection, etc, and adding virtualization to it seems impossible. So I think my only choice is to append more rows on demand to the sample table code I've provided above. I can't use hooks to store the `slicedRows` because it re-renders the entire component and I've to scroll from the beginning. So is there a way to append rows on-demand using Waypoint? If not can anyone suggest any other alternatives to add rows to DOM on demand?

Comment: I've added heights for rows and gave a maxHeight that is less than the sum of all rows, so definitely I'll need to scroll

Comment: Keep a reference to value of window scrolled so far

Comment: I have an iterable 'I' in map function which gives me reference of the current row, but my doubt is how do I append the next 20 rows from reference to existing rows, without re-rendering

Comment: You are updating data your React component is depending on - there'll be additional rerender for sure - no other way. Keeping the scroll value and restoring it after modifying the data is my suggestion

Comment: will using redux work? or any other sources for loading rows on demand?

Comment: Any way to fetch & store rows seems right to me at the moment. I mean it seems unrelated to the question

Answer (score 0):

Not precisely an answer to the question at hand, but re-renders are likely unavoidable. You can try to mitigate the performance hit by memoizing your cells (the below example uses `lodash` and `React.memo`):

```
const compareAccessors = (accessors, prevRow, nextRow) => (
  accessors.map((index) => (
    isEqual(get(prevRow, index, null), get(nextRow, index, null))
  )).reduce((last, next) => last && next, true)
);

const Cell = memo((cellData) => {
  const {
    cell,
    index,
  } = cellData;
  const tableCell = <Table.Cell key={index} {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</Table.Cell>;
  return tableCell;
}, (prevprops, nextprops) => {
  if (!nextprops.cell.column.accessors) {
    // simple comparison of single cell accessor
    return prevprops.cell.value == nextprops.cell.value;
  }
  // more complex comparison of accessors array on the cell.
  return compareAccessors(
    nextprops.cell.column.accessors,
    prevprops.cell.row.original,
    nextprops.cell.row.original,
  );
});
```

With usage something like this:

```
const columns =[
  {
    Header: 'Id',
    accessor: 'id',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Two Values',
    accessor: 'id',
    accessors: ['id', 'name'],
    Cell: ({row: { original: { id, name }}}) => (
      <div>${id}-${name}</div>
    )
  },
]
```

You can take it a step further and memoize your rows as well, but I am not including example code here.